# How to take input of own datatypes in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, input

I want to take input in an Array where the number of inputs is not fixed.

The input is as follows

```
3
3 ab ab bd
2 ab na
5 ab bl jhg fhd djbj
```

I have provided a sample input, the input is similar in a question.

At first number of inputs is provided that is 3.

Then each row may have I inputs that is for first 3 input strings, second 2 input strings and third 5 input strings.
Please help how can I store the input.

Comment: `List<List<String>>` would do it.

Comment: Use BufferedReader to read each line. Then you can use String#split() to create a String[] with your space-separated lines.

Answer (score 2):

I think this question is based on a misconception.

If you are putting data into an `ArrayList` (or most other `List` classes), *you do not need to tell the list how big it is going to be*.  You just call `add` to add each element to the list.  The `ArrayList` implementation takes care of the resizing<sup>1</sup>.  This also applies to a list of lists.

Having said that, if you really *need* to allocate an `ArrayList` with space for `N` elements<sup>2</sup>, the way to do it is to construct it like this:

```
ArrayList<Something> list = new ArrayList<>(N);
```

(Note that this is setting the *capacity* not the size of the list.  The list will return `0` as the size of the list ... until you add the elements.)

And the way to assemble a list of lists from an input file is to use nested loops.  The outer loop populates the outer list.  The inner loop reads the lines consisting of the list elements and populates the inner lists.

---

On the other hand ... if you are building an array, or an array of arrays, then each component array must be created with the correct size, because arrays cannot be resized.

---

<sup>1 - In some cases it is more efficient to tell the list how many elements it is likely to contain.  But in most cases, the performance difference makes no practical difference.  *Beware of premature optimization!!*

2 - Note that if your size estimate is incorrect, setting an incorrect capacity can actually be harmful for space utilization AND performance.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Use a list of lists.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
list.add(new ArrayList<String>());
list.get(0).add("Hello");
list.get(0).add("Me is");
list.get(0).add("Ded");

list.add(new ArrayList<String>());
list.get(1).add("Eh");
```

In the first element theres 3 elements, in the second there is 1.